# How to set Type/Interface for useMutation or useQuery hooks in component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, rtk-query

I want to utilise the interface with data returned from useMutation hooks in component, provided from RTK Query. how can I achive this.

Refer to code below:

In API Slice.

```
export const catsApi: any = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'catsApi',
    baseQuery: baseQueryWithReauth,
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        fetchCats: builder.query<IGenericResponse<ICatResponse>, any>({
            query: () => ({
                url: `cats`,
                method: "GET",
            }),
        }),
    }),
});
```

In component

```
const { isLoading: catsLoading, data: cats} = useFetchCatsQuery();
```

```
useEffect(() => {
  const catName = cats.<here i need keys from my ICatResponse>
}, [someDependancy]);
```

In component

```
const { isLoading: catsLoading, data: cats} = useFetchCatsQuery();
```